# Wordpress display Drive files to selective users

Tags: database, wordpress, user-interface, authentication, system

I created a WordPress plugin that pulls files and folders using the Google Drive API. I need to selectively display the files based on the user. There is one top level folder and each subfolder will be a project. I am thinking of creating a table that stores the user email and the folder ID they are allowed to view. When the user goes to their profile page, I query the db, then call the API with their folder ID. Is there a more efficient approach?